# How to store chunk of lines in variable in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a text file with 10000+ lines with chr and values per line. I need this information to run a program (called `TOOL` below). The text file `mylist19.list` looks like this:

```
chr1 1 12
chr1 14 34
chr1 44 65
chr1 48 88
chr1 88 93
chr1 122 144
```

I wan to run this in a batch of 99 lines. So this is what I did:

```
file="/scratch/mylist19.list" 

start=1
diff=99
LASTline=$(cat $file | wc -l)
while [ ${start} -le ${LASTline} ]; do
    CHUNK=sed -n `expr ${start},${diff}p` ${file}
    echo ${CHUNK}
    #TOOL --use ${CHUNK}
    start=$((${start}+${diff}))
done < ${file}
```

So how do I store the output of `sed -n expr ${start},${diff}p;${LASTline}q ${file}` in `CHUNK` so I can use it in the `TOOL` command? Also, I would like to include `$LASTline` in the last chunk.

Comment: Note that `expr` generally shouldn't be used in modern code -- it's an artifact of the 1970s and 80s, from before shells were guaranteed to have math support built in (which was added as a guarantee for standard-compliant `sh` implementations as of the 1992 publication of POSIX.2); as it calls an external executable for every invocation, it's _far_ slower than using that built-in arithmetic syntax.

Comment: Also, `wc -l <"$file"` is more efficient than `cat "$file" | wc -l`. It's a fairly small difference for `wc -l`, but for `wc -c` and big files the difference is _huge_, since with a real file it can skip straight to the end and ask for the current offset, but with a pipeline it has to read all the way to the end and count the number of bytes encountered on the way. (Other tools like `tail`, `sort` and `tac` also have similar shortcuts that make them far faster when you _don't_ provide their input through a pipeline).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about `sed` but since this is tagged as `bash` here is a solution without `sed` which might do what you wanted.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

diff=99
file="/scratch/mylist19.list" 

while mapfile -n "$diff" -t array && (( ${#array[*]} )); do
  chunk=("${array[@]}" "$file")
  echo "${chunk[@]}"
  echo tool --use "${chunk[@]}"
done < "$file"
```

---

> Also, I would like to include $LASTline in the last chunk.

Something like

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

diff=99
file="/scratch/mylist19.list"
total=$(wc -l < "$file")

while mapfile -n "$diff" -t array && (( ${#array[*]} )); do
  (( count += ${#array[*]} ))

  if (( total != count )); then
    chunk=("${array[@]}" "$file") 
  else
    chunk=("${array[@]}" "$file" "$total")
  fi

  echo "${chunk[@]}"
  echo tool --use "${chunk[@]}"
done < "$file"
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed, just a few changes to your script:

```
file="/scratch/mylist19.list"

start=1
diff=99
end=0
LASTline=$(cat $file | wc -l)
while [ ${start} -le ${LASTline} ]; do
    end=$((${end}+${diff}))
    CHUNK=$(sed -n "${start},${end}p" ${file})
    echo ${CHUNK}
    #TOOL --use ${CHUNK}
    start=$((${start}+${diff}))
done

CHUNK+=$'\n'"$LASTline"

echo "${CHUNK}"
```

Comment: I edited to enclose the variable with quotes. I think the real problem with my approach is that it doesn't really add a newline but a \n that is then interpreted by echo, and not that I've forgotten to enclose with quotes.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't actually know how to embed the newline in the variable. I'll edit again with your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm pretty new here :)

Comment: The syntax arithmetics, I just left it as OP used it. It's very noisy for me indeed, but for each one, it's cup of tea!